# unable to import pagseguro_urlpatterns from django_pagseguro.urls

Tags: python, django

I work with python 3 and install django-pagseguro.
I tried to run command in python shell:

```
from django_pagseguro.urls import pagseguro_urlpatterns
```

and getting error:

```
>>> from django_pagseguro.urls import pagseguro_urlpatterns
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\patff\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\k36\lib\site-packages\django_pagseguro\urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
ImportError: cannot import name 'patterns'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\patff\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\k36\lib\site-packages\django_pagseguro\urls.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, url
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.conf.urls.defaults'
```

Comment: did you add `django-pagseguro.` in your INSTALLED_APPS from settings.py ?

Comment: yes. I add django_pagseguro in INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: which version of Django that you use? make sure this package support this version

Answer (score 1):

django-paseguro [is trying to import `patterns`](https://github.com/fabiocerqueira/django-pagseguro/blob/master/django_pagseguro/urls.py), so it doesn’t support Django 1.10+. The failing import `django.conf.urls.defaults` is a fallback for Django < 1.6.

Comment: I use django 1.11. So, how can i install solve this? because i need to use django-pagseguro or something similar.

Comment: You can fork `django-pagseguro` and update it to be compatible with Django 1.11. You could search to see if somebody else has done that already. You could search for an alternative library that does the same thing - perhaps `django-pagseguro2` is an option? Or simply don't use `django-pagseguro` in your project. I'm not familiar with `django-pagseguro` so I can't give any more specific advice.